# Is there a circuit that conserves energy of multiple power sources?

Tags: batteries, battery-operated

Say I have several batteries. To start all the batteries are "dormant"; there is no current running through them. Starting with the first battery it runs current through it until it dies, wherein the next battery is activated and so on and so forth.

Is there a circuit that can do this? Would a circuit with batteries in series or parallel work?

Comment: What's the point? You want to have a bunch of reserve batteries that will get switched automatically to feed some device?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do it, easiest would be a BMS which activates each battery in turn. I suppose you could use this to cycle batteries and replace one set while running off the other set to keep your system up all the time while running. So to answer your question: "yes".

Comment: Depending on the battery type, it might be better for them to be wired in parallel and only use 1/n of their power at a time.